# Fixing the Kivy's minimize function

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently making a smart TV interface using kivy and selenium. I'm trying to make it where when I press the button on the interface it loads the browser and then minimizes the mainapp screen. Although the hide and minimize function both don't work for me. Then again I'm having a problem understanding how they work please help. Also any tips are much appreciated.

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from selenium import webdriver
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 'False')
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', 'True')
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
x = .25
y = .25
xpos = 1366/4
ypos = 768/3
#def returnapp():
#    while

def netflix_log(x):
    import kivy.core.window
    from kivy.core import window
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.fullscreen_window()
    driver.get("https://www.beta.netflix.com/login")
    driver.find_element_by_name("userLoginId").send_keys("1234")
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("1234")
    submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
    submit.click()
    hide(mainapp).run()
    return


netflix = Button(background_normal=('netflix.png'),
                 size_hint=(x, y),
                 pos=(0 + 10, ypos + 10),
                 on_press=netflix_log)
hulu = Button(background_normal=('hulu.png'),
              size_hint=(x, y),
              pos=(xpos, ypos))
youtube = Button(background_normal=('youtube.png'),
                 size_hint=(x, y),
                 pos=(xpos * 2, ypos))
fox = Button(background_normal=('fox.png'),
             size_hint=(x, y),
             pos=(xpos * 3, ypos))
amazon_prime = Button(background_normal=('amazon prime.png'),
                      size_hint=(x, y),
                      pos=(0, 0))
youtube_tv = Button(background_normal=('Youtubetv.png'),
                    size_hint=(x, y),
                    pos=(xpos, 0))
settings = Button(background_normal=("settings.png"),
                  size_hint=(x, y),
                  pos=(xpos * 2, 0))
applications = [netflix, hulu, youtube, fox, amazon_prime, youtube_tv, settings]


class mainapp(App):

    def build(self):
        print("e2")
        lay = FloatLayout()
        for i in applications:
            lay.add_widget(i)
        return lay

def settings_click():
    for items in applications:
        FloatLayout().remove_widget(items)
    for items in settings_menu:
        FloatLayout().add_widget(items)
        return FloatLayout()

mainapp().run()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "don't work". Does nothing at all happen? Is there an error message? If yes, please post it? Or does something else happen?

Comment: Try `App.get_running_app().root_window.minimize()`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Marc it was late last night. Nevertheless, thank you, John, it fixed my problem.